# How to return a value by transforming the value contained in an observable in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, rx-swift

I am very new to Swift and iOS so please bear with me. I am trying to set a computed property which is an observable .
something like this ..

```
var mySection: Observable<DashboardSection>{

return Observable.just(

// unpack an "O1" observable and transform it, re-wrap it in different class 

}
```

I have an O1 observable that is type

```
let O1 : Observable<[Class1?]>
```

in the computed property I want to extract the array from O1 observable and make some computations on it and then pack it into different class  and return it.

I have a piece of code which does exactly same thing using multiple sources `Observable.combineLatest(o1,o2,o2, resultSelector)` here the result selector can do this things and return the value but how do I do this for just a single source ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that's RxSwift there shouldn't be a need to use a computed property at all.
If the Dashboard logic will be valid for whole object lifetime typically you'd set it up using the `.map` in init like this:

```
import RxSwift

class SomeClass {
    let mySection: Observable<DashboardSection>

    init(o1: Observable<[Class1?]>) {
        mySection = o1.map { array in 
            //do the computations on array
            //return your DashboardSection value
        }
    }
}
```